# UI button triggers not functional in build, but work as intended in editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I am currently working to translate a VR game to the Oculus Quest 2 from a PC standalone version.  In this game, I have created a VR menu with UI buttons that include triggers. These triggers have  a script attached that when touched by the player, it will simulate the button being clicked.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.name == "LeftHandAnchor" || other.gameObject.name == "RightHandAnchor")
        {
            this.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

This works as intended in the Unity Editor, however, when I build the game, none of the triggers work as the should. I am unsure what the reason could be.

Update:
I have adjusted the above code so that instead of looking for the objects named `LeftHandAnchor` and `RightHandAnchor`, I replaced these lines to look for tags instead.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "VRController" || other.gameObject.tag == "LeftHand" || other.gameObject.tag == "RightHand")
        {
            this.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

Just as before, however, this works only in the editor and not in the .apk build.

Comment: maybe the names don't match in a build?

Comment: As in the trigger names?

Comment: what does "none of the triggers work as they should" mean?  They don't fire at all, they fire but the IF section is skipped, some other unrelated code is fired?

Comment: Yeah I probably should've clarified that. I attached empty game objects to the UI buttons and added box colliders to them, and checked the "Is Trigger" box in the properties panel. This is meant to allow the player to touch the trigger, which will invoke the button click.

Comment: so the event isn't firing at all, correct?

Comment: Not at all, yes that is correct.

Comment: it's been awhile, but is there a z-order you need to worry about?  perhaps the empty object is 'underneath' the other objects.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the problem, as everything seems to be on the same layer.

Comment: Please try and debug the build. Before the IF statements , add a visual text debug and see if the collision is even being captured in VR. Try -
void onTriggerEnter(Collider col){ onScreenText.text = col.gameObject.tag + " and " +col.gameObject. name; }